# Can't pattern match on HttpMethod

Tags: f#

This does not compile. Why? The error message is confusing, why does the property not existing in the pattern?

```
match System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post with
| System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post -> "post"
| _ -> "other"
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the [F# reference documentation on pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching), you'll see that the first type of pattern that you can match against is a constant pattern, described as "Any numeric, character, or string literal, an enumeration constant, or a defined literal identifier." These are all *compile-time* constants, so that the compiler can safely compile it to a single value in the compiled IL code. However, [System.Net.HttpMethod.Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmethod.post?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpMethod_Post) is not an enum value, it's a static property of the `HttpMethod` class. A property cannot be safely compiled to a constant value, as the class in question could do anything (including side-effects) when the property is accessed.

This is why you cannot pattern-match against `System.Net.HttpMethod.Post`: it's not a compile-time constant. You'd instead have to do something like:

```
match System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post with
| method when method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post -> "post"
| _ -> "other"
```

This is legal F# syntax, and will compile. Slightly awkward, yes, but that's the result of this intersection between the F# compiler rules and how the .Net library was designed.